# php form does not work

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to create a form that would send the data to my email, but when I test the form, I get "this webpage is not found/ No webpage was found for the web address: file:///C:/Users/Masha/Dropbox/nam%20fp/contact.php". And, my email box is empty as well.

Here's my html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "mystylec.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>
    CONTACT
</h1>

<? = $thankYou ?>

<form method = "post" action = "contact.php">
    <br><br> e-mail: <br>
    <input type = "text" name = "senderEmail" value = "" required>
    <br><br>
    name: <br>
    <input type = "text" name = "sender" value = "">
    <br><br>
    comment: <br>
    <textarea name = "comment" rows = "10" cols = "30"></textarea required>
    <br><br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit">
</form>
<h3>
<img src = "https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/5301/julia- kropacheva.27/0_59f4f_6bb21bc3_orig" alt = "uzor" style = "width:468px;height:755px;"/>
</h3>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my php:

```
if($_POST["submit"])
{
$recipient = "mashashapa@yandex.ru";
$subject = "NAM Advertising request";
$sender = $_POST["sender"];
$senderEmail = $_POST["senderEmail"];
$message = $_POST["comment"];

$mailBody = "Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$comment";

mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender $sender <$senderEmail>");

$thankyou = "<p> Thank you! Your form has been submitted. </p>";
}

?>
```

Also, I attached screenshots of what happens when I try to submit the form.

[image]
[image]

Thank you all! I feel like this might be a simple problem, but I just started coding so I don't get a lot of stuff.

Comment: From your screenshots, I can see that you are running your php page directly, that is, not from a php server. Please run the `php` page from a php server.

Comment: You can't test php files using `file://`. Do you have a server installed locally?

Comment: Install `WAMP` or `XAMP` see this HOWTO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMqUG4E2M0M

Comment: @Masha312 You have an attribute in the end tag to your textarea. That is incorrect; only start tags can have attributes.

Comment: I would suggest to learn how to run php pages, first few links in google should help you get started. ampps, xampp are the stacks you must look at.

Comment: @Script47 In all honesty, that's just personal preference - it doesn't matter to the question at all. :-)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side language. This means that PHP script must be served by a web server(such as Apache) that has PHP installed. Every time your script is called, the web server will call and then wait for PHP to execute your code before showing you the results it generates.

Have a look at this link that @Armen had mentioned in the comments: [How to configure your XAMPP server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMqUG4E2M0M)

Answer (score 1):

In order to test PHP, you have to do it on a server (PHP is a server-side scripting language). The best way to do this will be to use something like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) which function as your local server on which you can test your scripts etc. before deploying them. Since you are running Windows, it is just a matter of taste as to which one to choose.

Read the documentation and happy scripting.